# Make a clickable, animated hover using css only

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, pointer-events

The point is making an `aside` element enter when you hover on an image, using only CSS, but also, let its children accept click events.

So far what I have is a functioning animated hover, which has a button in it and that button *does* act on click events. I have used `pointer-events: none` on the sliding `aside` element, because otherwise the animation is jumpy to the point of breaking, So, `pointer-events: none` gets that out of the way and the animation is smooth and persistent as long as you're hovering.

The problem occurs when you hover on the *button*. It will make the `aside` transition out (see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whwy1wrv/1/), it's better than my broken English).

I'm looking for a way to prevent the `aside` from returning to its initial, hidden position. And the challenge of course, is using CSS only!

Here is the code (it's also in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whwy1wrv/1/)):

HTML:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="http://i59.tinypic.com/10cvw8y.jpg" class="template-img">
  <aside tab-index="1" class="hover">
    <button class="button" onclick="alert('wow')">CLICK ME</button>
  </aside>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.template-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.template-img:hover ~ .hover {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.template-img:focus {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.template-img:focus ~ .hover {
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: none;
}

.hover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 15%;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform .4s ease-out;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
  z-index: 10;
}

.button {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the style below seems to fixed the problem

```
.hover:hover {
 transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Forcing the animation to run when hovering the content as well

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whwy1wrv/2/)

Comment: OMFG. That was so simple and I've been breaking my head over this forever! Haha :D